# Can an ethereum token name have numbers in them?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

So let's say a token is called USDC. Well can we have one called 1usd or 43g something like that? Or must they all be uppercase letters. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be a problem since the name instance of the token is `string` which can contain numbers as well. [0x](https://www.gemini.com/prices/0x?utm_source=google&utm_campaignID=16064093708&utm_adgroupID=135835907914&utm_creativeID=579133637929&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=&utm_term=&gclid=CjwKCAjw0a-SBhBkEiwApljU0lNwmM9McsffVH9B5wtymrOF3iWolzumX61Kqp3RhnTCGJl0rNgNMBoCjkYQAvD_BwE) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20#token), both name and symbol are strings.
Therefore you can use numbers for the token name.